# Get text from selected option

Tags: select, angular

I have a form with some `<select>` bound to an object comming from a webservice :

```
<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.type" name="type" id="type">
        <option value="0">Disabled</option>
        <option value="1">Day</option>
        <option value="2">Week</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.days" name="days" id="days">
        <option value="0">Monday</option>
        <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

Everything work as expected on this side.

I need to add at the end of my form a sentence which is a summary of the users's choice.
Something like :

```
<span> You selected type {{configDatas.type}} with day {{configDatas.days}}</span>
```

but instead of the value i'm looking for the text of the option. 
I would like to see something like :

> You selected type Week with day Monday

Is this possible directly in the template without using any kind of conversion on the component side ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**: You can use the change event to keep track of the newly selected option:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.type" name="type" id="type" #type (change)="updateType(type.options[type.value].text)">
    <option value="0">Disabled</option>
    <option value="1">Day</option>
    <option value="2">Week</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.days" name="days" id="days" #days (change)="updateDay(days.options[days.value].text)">
        <option value="0">Monday</option>
        <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
</select>

<span> You selected type {{selectedType}} with day {{selectedDay}}</span>



export class App {
  configDatas: any;
  selectedType: string;
  selectedDay: string;

  constructor() {
    this.configDatas = {
      'type': '', 
      'days': ''
    };
  }

  updateType(text: string) {
    this.selectedType = text;
  }

  updateDay(text: string) {
    this.selectedDay = text;
  }
}
```

**Updated Example http://plnkr.co/edit/ay7lgZh0SyebD6WzAerf**

Comment: Value cannot be changed , my data provider require numerical value

Comment: I am updating my answer now for a much better solution to match your scenario

Answer (score 6):

This may be a version difference, but the accepted answer didn't work for me.  But pretty close did.  this is what did the trick for me.

```
(change)="updateType(type.options[type.options.selectedIndex].text)
```

Comment: If you are working on angular version 4.x.x this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this is to use complex objects for your select list options.

You declare an interface for your options:

`export interface Day {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}`

Give it some options in the constructor:

`this.days = [
  {id: 0, text: 'Monday'},
  {id: 0, text: 'Tuesday'},
  {id: 0, text: 'Wednesday'}
];`

Bind it to the option list. It's important to use **ngValue** here:

`<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.days" name="days" id="days">
  <option *ngFor="let day of days" [ngValue]="day">{{day.text}}</option>
</select>`

And finally output it:

`<span> You selected type {{selectedType}} with day Id: {{configDatas.days.id}}, Text: {{configDatas.days.text}}</span>`

Full example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kDanyC

Answer (score 1):

In html, add event listener (change)="onSelectionChanged($event)"

```
<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.days" name="days" id="days" (change)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
    <option value="0">Monday</option>
    <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

In typescript, use event.target.selectedOptions[0].text to get the selected text (assume that it's single select)

```
onSelectionChanged(event: any) {
   console.log(event.target.selectedOptions[0].text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible without keeping a separate array for each select ?

Not sure of the aversion to using two arrays to solve this but two functions could fix it.

```
<span> You selected type {{displayType(configDatas.type)}} with day {{displayDate(configDatas.days)}}</span>
```

Then just have some functions that return the text you want.

```
displayType(type) : string {
  if (type == 0) {
    return "disabled"
  } else { //continue adding ifs
    return ""
  }
}
```

A objectively nicer way would to have two arrays that contain both the id and the text to display and then use a `*ngFor` to build the options up.

Comment: There is no aversion to use an array , i was just hoping i can get directly the value like i would have with the DOM. Lot of the select (there more than 2) have 2 or 3 options , it's just quicker for me to write it in plain html rather than defining an array and displaying it with ngFor

Answer (score 0):

In simple way to get selected option text using (change)="selectDay($event)" event

```
<select [(ngModel)]="configDatas.days" name="days" id="days" (change)="selectDay($event)">
    <option value="0">Monday</option>
    <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

In TS File

```
selectCity(event:any) {
  console.log(event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text);
  let day = event.target[event.target.selectedIndex].text;
}
```